# An Android Service constantly performing some different jobs depending on each other

Tags: android

I want to constantly, without stopping, perform 2-3 kinds of operations from my Service in Android. That is:

- check if some hardware is connected and retrieve the data from it every 1 second and save it to the files
- send those files a server
- perform some calculations

The second job depends on the 1st one.

Note that the Service will have GUI as well if that matters, but the GUI will be used rarely. Most of them time the Service will work in "background" doing what it has to do.

How can I do that? Should there be 3 different threads or what? Or I don't need the thread because it'll be a service?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what type of service you are using, **Intent Service** or **Service**.

If you are using Intent Service, then you don't have to worry about creating a new thread, as it itself creates a worker thread.But, just keep in mind that, it takes one care of requests one at a time, in queue manner and stops itself when the processing is done.

But if you want to perform simultaneous request at once, extend from **Service**. You will have create a worker thread to run this service as it doesn't create a separate thread.

Check developer guide for more info:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

To communicate between two services, you have to make use of **Broadcast** **Receiver** to receive intents which you can send from your first service or use listener callback, but i would suggest you to use Broadcast Receiver and intents.

Comment: but also I have 2 or 3 different kinds of jobs, not only one which is sending http requests.

Comment: basically, you want to run 2 or 3 service at once in background, and it should be when it finishes it processing.Let's say your first service is downloading file and second one is downloading image. In, this scenario you can start  2 service,which will run in background even when your app is killed and will stop once its done.

Comment: well, they should somehow communicate with each other I guess. That is, the 1st one retrieve some data from USB and saves it into the files, the 2nd one sends those files to a server. How could I do that?

Comment: Ok. And why not 3 threads in one Service but 3 different Services each for each job (retrieving the data from USB, sending it to a server, calculations)? Is there any benefits in the 1st solution over the 2nd one?

Comment: you don't have to create three services, create one service for 3 threads.But, if you are using an intent service, you won't be able to perform multiple request as it handles one request at a time. So, in your scenario, extend directly from Service class and execute three request. you can also set the priority of each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform all operation in parallel in background then use android service and use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class to achieve this.
Otherwise use timer or Executor(with onr thread) inside android service to perform all operation in serial manner.
Let me know, This is helpful for you?

Comment: I don't know, which is recommendable?

Comment: I think, You should use Service with one timer with specified interval and execute all condition "as you have given above" inside that timer.